# Django Postgres Case Insensitive Textfield and citext

Tags: django, postgresql, python-3.x

for my Django app i use PostgreSQL (9.3) and i want to use case insensitive text in my database. For this Popstgres has a 'new' extension named 'citext'.

As i understand it, django can't use this extension out of the box, so i have made an custom field:

```
class RsCharField(models.CharField):
    ...
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'citext'
```

I use a CharField as baseclass, because i still want all the django perks of being able to set a maximum length and the validators that come with that.

The database is created correctly and i end up with citext-tables:

```
 description       | citext                   | not null
```

But when i do a query, django translates te query to:

```
SELECT * FROM .... WHERE mytable.description::text LIKE 'TEST%'
```

which still is case sensitive. When i do a manual select and drop the ::text it works case-insensitive.

**Question**: What am i doing wrong, and how can i make my CharFields behave like case-insensitive fields in django when doing queries?

note: most importantly i want my indexes to behave like case insensitive indexes.

Comment: Can you share your queryset filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the classes provided in django.contrib.postgres.fields.citext
https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/1.11/_modules/django/contrib/postgres/fields/citext/